# Change fasta header based on regex pattern

Tags: regex, awk, fasta

I have a fasta files with headers in two patterns like this

```
>256_Org1 
MAVVIIKDAADDSLARRD

>Org2_10005 
DSLARRDMAVVIIKDAA
```

I want to retain only the words and remove the numbers. I tried to use awk one liners suggested, but separating with delimiter `'_'` and following with `{print $1}` gives `256` (wrong) or `Org2` (right). The output I expect is

```
>Org1 
MAVVIIKDAADDSLARRD

>Org2 
DSLARRDMAVVIIKDAA
```

In textwrangler, I can replace it in two steps, *1* with `\>\d+\_` to `>` and *2* with `\_\d+\n` to `\n`. But I have several hundred files and would like to use a one-liner. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the actual Awk code you tried?

Comment: With jjust two examples it's hard to figure out how to generalize this. Would it be a good guess that on lines starting with `>` if we apply `_` as a field separator on the string after the `>` wedge, any all-numeric field should be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^>[0-9]+_/>/; s/_[0-9]+ *$//' file
```

Output:

```
>Org1 
MAVVIIKDAADDSLARRD

>Org2
DSLARRDMAVVIIKDAA
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter for FASTA file format that the second substitution would zap `_[0-9]+ *$` on non-header lines because this pattern can only match in a header line. Perhaps still worth pointing out as a minor caveat.

Comment: It works when I implement a file one by one. I tried to create a batch file with perl in the following way:     system('sed -E q{s/^>[0-9]+_/>/; s/_[0-9]+ *$//} infile1.fas >outfile1.fas');   After execution, it says sh:1 : s/_[0-9]+: not found
sh: 1: cannot create [0-9]+_/: Is a directory

Comment: @Arun: I don't know where you integrate the sed command. I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: @Cyrus. Solved it. I tried to integrate it in perl batch file with system command. I had to just mask the escaping of backslashes by perl. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` solution may help you in same too.

```
awk 'NF && />/ && /[0-9]+/{sub(/_[0-9]+/,"");sub(/[0-9]+_/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: `NF` is trivially true if `/>/` so maybe that condition could be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` script:

```
/^>/!b                 # if it's not a FASTA header line, don't touch it
s/\([>_]\)[0-9]*_/\1/g # zap internal all-numeric field
s/_[0-9]*$//           # zap terminal all-numeric field if present
```

As a `sed` one-liner you can apply to all your files:

```
sed -i~ -e '/^>/!b' -e 's/\([>_]\)[0-9]*_/\1/g' -e 's/_[0-9]*$//' *.fasta
```

The `-i~` causes `sed` to perform in-place replacement with the original file backed up as the filename with a tilde appended at the end.

Not all `sed` implementations like multiple `-e` arguments and I was slightly sloppy with `[0-9]*` because not all `sed` dialects have a way to say `[0-9]+` which would be more proper here.  If you have `sed -r` or `sed -E` that would be a nice improvement but again, without information about which platform you're on, I don't want to post speculative variations.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work. I am using ubuntu terminal. it executes but files are unchanged.